# Open .exe file in android studio?

Tags: android

I am new to android studio an was wondering  that can we embed .exe file in android studio? Is there a way I can open and execute .exe file on button click in android?

Comment: it is same as asking how to run an apk on windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that. A .exe file is a windows executable. It won't run on Android, which is a Linux based operating system.